# Error after enabling secure boot

Tags: secure-boot

I am using msi motherboard
Having windows 11
After i went to bios to enable secure boot for the valorant's requirement. The I saved and exit the bios setting, then the computer starting restarting and keep on restarting itself every 5s endlessly. The screen doesnt even appear and I cannot even access to bios setting to undo

Comment: What kind of GPU do you have installed? (It also needs Secure Boot support for video to work during firmware start, although still shouldn't cause reboots.) When you enabled Secure Boot, was there an option to enable "UEFI Third-Party CA" or something like that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you pull the CMOS battery, or is there a BIOS reset jumper? Check your mainboard documentation about resetting your BIOS.

Comment: I am using Galax 2060 super, when i enabled secure, there is something require me to do before enabling which is something set new key for platform key (PK) in the key management

Comment: I've tried remove the CMOS battery for certain amount of time, still it doesnt reset my bios to factory setting. The same problem still occur

Comment: B460M PRO-VDH WIFI (mainboard). Here is what happened in specific. I went to bios setting to enable secure boot, it tell me to set new platform key (PK) in "Key management" before enable Secure Boot. Then after I enable secure boot then "Save changes and Exit". My computer starting turn on for literally 5s and off (then repeat itself non-stop). I cannot access to bios setting again